# how to display error message if dropdown list item doesnt have matching records in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

In aspx page i have: 2 dropdown lists(both databound and outside gridview) , one search button and GridView1. Im using stored procedure in sql. One dropdown is MainMenu and other is  category.If i select an item from MainMenu ,Category dropdown will load corresponding categories. When i click search button Gridview1 will show rows matching these selection. My problem: If there are no rows matching dropdown selections ,error msg should be displayed which is not displayed.i tried several ways but in vain. However there is no error. Pls help with the code.

Stored Procedure:

```
 ALTER  PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SearchStentRecords_Sp]
                @Action VARCHAR(10)
               ,@ddl1  VARCHAR(50)
               ,@ddl2 VARCHAR(50)
               , @ERROR int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Addstock where Addstock.Device=@ddl1)


    BEGIN 
       set @ERROR=1
        IF @Action = 'SELECT1'
            BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM Addstock where Addstock.Device=@ddl1 AND Addstock.Category=@ddl2 AND Used='N' AND TakenBack='N'
             END

    ELSE IF @Action = 'SELECT2'
                BEGIN
                SELECT * FROM Addstock where Addstock.Device=@ddl1 AND Used='N' AND TakenBack='N'
               END
     END                   
   ELSE 
             BEGIN
             SET @ERROR= 0
             END

END
```

Code behind for search button click method:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
                try
                {


                    if (ddlMainmenu.SelectedIndex != 0 && ddlStentCat.SelectedIndex != 0)
                    {

                        cmd = new SqlCommand("SearchStentRecords_Sp", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT1");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddl1", ddlMainmenu.SelectedItem.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddl2", ddlStentCat.SelectedItem.Text);
                        SqlParameter resultParam= new SqlParameter("@ERROR", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                        resultParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(resultParam);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        int retVal;

                        int.TryParse(resultParam.Value.ToString(),out retVal);
                        if (retVal == 1)
                        {

                            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            adp.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                        else if(retVal==0)
                        {
                            GridView1.Visible=false;
                            lblErrormsg.Text = "No Records Found";
                        }


                    }
                    else if (ddlMainmenu.SelectedIndex != 0 && ddlStentCat.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {


                        cmd = new SqlCommand("SearchStentRecords_Sp", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT2");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddl1", ddlMainmenu.SelectedItem.Text);
                        SqlParameter resultParam= new SqlParameter("@ERROR", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                        resultParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(resultParam);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        int retVal;
                            //= (int)cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;
                        int.TryParse(resultParam.Value.ToString(),out retVal);
                        if (retVal==1)
                        {
                            adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            adp.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                        else if(retVal==0)
                        {
                            lblErrormsg.Text = "No Records Found";
                        }

                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();

                }
            }

        }
```

for example. Suppose dropdown1 has items: Car,Bikes. And Car has subcategories: BMW,Honda City. Bikes doesnt hav subcategories. Because im adding Items to both dropdown lists through other aspx pages hence dropdown lists are databound. NOw when i select Car , 2nd dropdown ll load BMW,Hond City. Suppose i click BMW and search button--> gridview will show following:

```
MainCategory                    Category             Colour

    Car                        BMW                Black
```

And now if select  Bike and click search button Gridview remains same. It should display NO Match found because there is no subcategory added for bike hence no record.  My problem is when search button clicked, dropdown item Bike should match any row in gridview with Bike. how to check this? I agree it was easier if i deployed dropdown inside gridview but since 2nd dropdown is dependent on 1st i didnt go for it to avoid complication. this is my problem.

Comment: Debug your code and Check the value of `retVal` variable. Since your are equaling it with 0, even if its not 0, it will still not show that message.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons here that its not working as expected is that you have `SELECT1` and `SELECT2` query names in your code-behind and these are the only two cases you are using. Whereas in your Procedure, you are using `IF...ELSE` on `SELECT1` and `SELECT2` and returning `@Error=0` only when its not either one of `SELECT1` or `SELECT2`. That means logically, you will never get 0 as output unless you pass something else other than `SELECT1` or `SELECT2`. I hope this is clear.

Additionally, you can put `TRY` and `CATCH` in your procedure to make sure you are not receiving an exception in your procedure that returns incorrect values. Also its a good coding practice.

When your query returns no rows, you can set `@Error=0` there and return 0 as the output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but sir outside if else there is IF EXISTS. At the end ELSE loop executes IF NOT exists set ERROR=0..sir  still confused how to modify the code/stored procedure. It wud be great if write the corrected code..thanku

Comment: So you just want to show 0 when there are no rows in your query, right ?

Comment: i hav edited the question.pls check at the end. Its not rows.count=0 set error=0. My prob is: if no match found in gridview then show No Matching Data  found

Comment: Just to clear my confusion, are you getting `retVal=0` from your procedure right now when there are no rows ?

Comment: i dont want that sir..that cant be easily done by checking the condition..if (ds.rows.count<0) then no rows in entire gridview. This is required wen there is no row for any of the selection made. My question is: for certain dropdown items if there are no records then how to show error msg?

Comment: You have used `lblErrormsg.Text` in both of your conditions, so doesn't it display the message text ?

Comment: no error msg is not displayed anywhere. so its clear that Error=0 is not returned from stored procedure. pls tell how to get error=0 from stored procedure. everything seems correct. pls re write stored procedure according to your logic